# How would I set up this rails relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three rails models: Usage(month, amount), Project(title, description) & Project_savings(amount).

Each project will have a project_saving.amount associated with it for every instance of usage.month. So, each usage will have_many project_savings (one for each project) and each project will have_many project_savings (one for each usage month). Each project_saving.amount for each project is equal to usage.amount for that month.

I was trying to do this like so:

```
Project has_many :project_savings,
        has_many :usages, through :project_savings

Usage   has_many :project_savings
        has_many :projects, through :project_savings

Project_saving belongs_to :usage, :project
```

Would I put the code to calculate this in the project_savings model? If I put the following in my ProjectSaving model:

```
Project.all.each do |p|
  Usage.all.each do |u|
    p.create_project_saving(amount: u.amount)
  end
end
```

Would this associate both the usage_id and project_id to the project_saving automatically, or would I need to manually put in `p.create_project_saving(usage_id:u.id, amount:u.amount)`??

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your text is quite confusing.

I think an important first step would be reading the railsguide about associations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Now with regard to the question "Should i set up a :through somehwere here?":

A has_many :through relationship is used if you have a relationship model which is a independent entity. Simply put, only if you actually want to add something to the relationship itself you should use has_many :through. Otherwise, you would use the simpler has_and_belongs_to_many association (with a join table).

If you want me to give a more concrete answer to your post, you should really think about how you want your models to interact with each other. For example, is Project_saving a related to both Usage and Project or is does it only belong to Project? Etc. your description makes it hard to decipher what you actually want your models to do.

Comment: Yeah I'm finding it quite hard to work out what I want to be honest, I thought the question was a bit cryptic after I reread it! I think I'll resubmit a new one and link to it here when I get home this evening.

Comment: You could just edit your question. If I would take a guess now it seems you need a nested has_many :through, as in: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association (just before 2.5)

Comment: Cheers @PeterdeRidder, I had actually just read through that before posting the question, but was a bit too tired to make sense! In any case, I've updated the question now, if you can make sense of it!